# LLDB fails to examine variables (in Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

In particular the `print` command typically (80-90% failure rate) does not work

I've verified already:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1947/_index.html

Example 1

> (lldb) p prevMsg

error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of runOnce: extracting data from value failed error: errored out in DoExecute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression

Example 2 A more typical example that puts you in a stone age of computing:

> (lldb) p activeNetworkRequests

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1700530). The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

This seems to have gotten progressively worse since Xcode 7.

Printing variables scoped from the enclosing function of a closure are particularly hopeless.

The code base is not small, about 15K lines. It would not be practical to isolate and reproduce all the code here.

Surely others are experiencing this?

UPDATE: I'm told about the merits of expression --unwind-on-error=0 -- variable-in-question, presumably for example2

UPDATE 2:

Code:

```
Util.log("Returning \(key) from file cache", [.Caches])
```

Output:

```
08:03:11.201 v2.0.64d other TwoStageCache.swift objectForKey(_:completion:)[95]: Returning https://example.server.com/Storage/Retrieve?FileName=accounts/person@domain.com/resource/47a58660-26d1-11e7-8e7f-c9f4cd679b03.html from file cache
```

(So the value of `key` is fine)

```
(lldb) fr var key
(URL) key = unable to read data
(lldb) print key
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1d787583).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

If we look at the crash:

```
(lldb) expression --unwind-on-error=0 -- key

libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain:
    0x22562b0 <+0>:  pushl  %ebp
    0x22562b1 <+1>:  movl   %esp, %ebp
    0x22562b3 <+3>:  subl   $0x8, %esp
    0x22562b6 <+6>:  calll  0x22562bb                 ; <+11>
    0x22562bb <+11>: popl   %ecx
    0x22562bc <+12>: movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
    0x22562bf <+15>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x22562c1 <+17>: je     0x22562e1                 ; <+49>
    0x22562c3 <+19>: movl   (%eax), %edx
->  0x22562c5 <+21>: testb  $0x2, 0x10(%edx)
```

From:

```
1 $__lldb_expr(UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>) -> ()
2 Beta Viewer`@objc AppDelegate.init() -> AppDelegate:
3 sharedEnchantment`partial apply for TwoStageCache.(objectForKey(URL, completion : (imgData : Data?, err : BBError?) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1)
4 sharedEnchantment`thunk:
```

Comment: use `po [yourVariable]`

Comment: that works in some cases, thankfully(?) producing less verbose output than p. I'd have to accumulate more statistics on po vs p

Comment: What is "key" in this case?  Is it an ivar, a local variable, argument, etc?  And what is its type?  You can do "frame var -L key" that will print where the debug information told us it was.  Clearly that wasn't where it was, which is why the expression crashed trying to access it.  But the question is in this case why we thought it was where it wasn't.  If you can file a bug with swift.org that's probably a better forum for back and forth investigation of this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry in advance for the essay, but hopefully the info will be worth the read...

lldb has two ways of looking at variables(*): `print` and `frame variable`.

`print` isn't really meant primarily for printing variables - that's just a side effect of what it really does.  `print` is an alias for `expression` which gives you a little more sense of what it is: a full expression evaluator which runs the expression you pass at the point where you are stopped in your code.

It builds a context that emulates the code at the current pc (including the Class/Protocol context) and then takes the snippet you pass it, compiles it in that context, JIT's the result, inserts the JIT'ed code into the process you are debugging and runs it.  That's quite powerful - you can change values, call functions in your program, introduce new functions, new types, etc.  But there is also a lot of machinery just to get it going, and with swift some of this machinery is tricky to get right.

`frame variable` can only print locals and arguments in the current frame (with the `-g` flag it can also print globals & statics).  It can't call functions, or any of the other fancy things `print` can do.  It does understand a limited subset of the variable access syntax, so:

(lldb) frame variable foo.bar.baz

will work.  But under the covers, all it needs to do is read the debug information to find the variable, its type, and where it is in memory, and then it can extract the value from that information.  So it is faster and more robust for what it does do - which is a large percentage of the work people generally ask `print` to do.

Note, you can get "object printing" for variables you access with `frame variable` by using the `-O` flag, and it supports the same formatting options for results as `print`.  For context, the Xcode "Locals" view is roughly equivalent to calling `frame variable`.

I tend to use `frame variable` for simple locals printing, but even if you like to use one command for all your needs - which will be `print` - it's good to know that there's a fallback if `print` is failing for some reason.

Back to your examples...

Example 1: one of the things `print` does in Swift is introduce all the visible local variables into the context of the expression, so they are available to your code.  The error in Example 1 is because one of the local variables couldn't be realized - maybe it was a only specified by a protocol conformance and we couldn't figure out what it really was - so we failed building the context, which means the parse or JIT steps failed.  The `print` code does a pre-scan for this sort of failure and omits failing locals, but you've found a case this scan misses.

`frame variable` would have probably also failed to print `runOnce` but since it doesn't depend on the current context, the inability to do that wouldn't have affected your ability to print other variables.

If you can reproduce this issue, even if you can't make the project available to us we can often figure out what's going on from lldb's debugging log.  So drive the debug session to the point where the print is going to fail, and do:

```
(lldb) log enable -f /tmp/lldb-log.txt lldb expr types
```

then run the failing expression.  Then grab that log, and file a bug as described here:

https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs

Example 2: Was activeNetworkRequests a property?  Those require us to call the "get" method to access them, and I have seen a few cases where lldb doesn't emit the code to call the property getters correctly.  The log above will show us the code that was emitted, and we might be able to tell from there what went wrong.  Of course, if you can make a test case you can send with the bug that is always best, but that's often not possible...

(*)For gdb users this is pretty close to the `info locals` vrs. `print`...

Comment: No wonder `print varname` is so slow sometimes. On the first run arrival at a breakpoint, I have found 15 seconds is not unusual.

Comment: So this is great, but problem still intractable. See edits

Comment: frame variable apparently has less rope to hang itself given that unlike p & po it works with and without -L

Comment: `(lldb) po durationSeconds
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'durationSeconds'`
... so ...
`(lldb) frame variable durationSeconds
(Float64) durationSeconds = <variable not available>`

Comment: The frame var error is because the variable doesn't currently have a known location.  In optimized code, if a variable isn't being used, it's the optimizer's job to make sure it isn't wasting space for it.  Swift does more code optimization as a matter of course even at -Onone, so you will see variables without known locations more often with Swift at -Onone than with C-family languages at -O0.

Comment: Note that in this case, the expression parser was doing the "right" thing.  It knew it couldn't realize the variable `durationSeconds`, so it didn't introduce it into the expression context.  Because of that, from the compiler's point of view `durationSeconds` was an unresolved identifier.  The failure there is that we haven't yet taught lldb to rewrite the compiler errors when it has supplementary information.

Comment: printing globals similarly falls flat on its face: p bf.accountMaster.count error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1740ed0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: bf is a global public var bf: Whateverprotocol!

Comment: @JimIngham Can we have a `-OnoneAndIReallyMeanNone` ?

Comment: Probably not as such.  Experiments to that end showed that some of the lower level optimizations swift does are necessary to have acceptable performance even by the lights of -Onone code.  It is not impossible to do optimizations and preserve debug info quality.  Swift has gotten much better at this as it has matured, and the team is dedicated to continuing this progress.  You can help by reporting the bugs you come across.  This sort of bug generally requires the original source, which is hard for some teams to provide.  But whenever you can please file any issues you see.

Comment: @JimIngham Debugging protocol oriented code is simply impossible.